# Can someone tell me what does this flutter error means?

Tags: flutter, dart

while I was running my Flutter app this error appear out of nowhere and I don't really understand it.

**The relevant error-causing widget was:
FutureBuilder
FutureBuilder:file:///home/chayut/flutter-quiz-app/lib/widgets/image/image_container.dart:292:12**

Does this mean my error is cause at line 292 and what does the number 12 mean?

Update:
Here is the full error log.
I don't know what's causing this error.

```
    ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following FormatException was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state:
_FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#d3c0c):
Invalid character (at character 6)
     ^
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  FutureBuilder<dynamic>
FutureBuilder:file:///home/blank/flutter-quiz-app/lib/widgets/image/image_container.dart:292:12

lib/…/image/image_container.dart:292
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2659:18                           buildScope
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 891:9                               drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 370:5                             [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1146:15                           [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1083:9                            handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 997:5                             [_handleDrawFrame]
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1090:13                           invoke
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 160:5                             invokeOnDrawFrame
lib/_engine/engine/initialization.dart 194:45                                 <fn>
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 99355 pixels on the bottom.
```

Comment: Please include the full error log

Comment: Well basically your image widget is unable to find the image in the location due to an invalid character which is thus causing renderflex error. It is in line 292 of the dart file image_container.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the above link in your debug console, it will directly take you to the error causing widget. Try to debug it, else post your code here so that we could help you out

Answer (score 0):

Its column :  [image]

its like line no 292 :  123456789101112 [Columns]